# UIViews with subviews: calculating position when scaling

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I have a view that I draw using Core Graphics, which in this example is a segmented circle. The user can touch the circle to create a point along its circumference; this creates a subview on the UIView that contains the circle graphic.

Then I've implemented a pinch-zoom gesture which causes the circle to redraw to its new size. I've seen most implementations of pinch zoom use `transform` properties, but I've chosen to redraw because it's all vectors and gives a clean result.

My problem is repositioning the point views. I calculate the required position of those points based on the scale of the parent view: as it changes I update the x/y coords of the point views. However, it seems there are some precision issues: as the circle shape size increases, the points drift so they aren't right on the line anymore. Here's a couple examples:

[image: a black point on a green circle segment]

This is where the circle is at 100% scale. Note the perfect positioning of that black point. But when you zoom in...

[image]

The point drifts off-line.

And here's some code. I derive the new size of the circle from the pinch gesture's scale (I modify if a bit to constrain and slow it down for UI purposes, so that's `deltaScale`) and then draw it like so:

```
let currentSize = self.shape!.bounds.size

let newSize = CGSize(width: self.originalSize.width * deltaScale, height: self.originalSize.height * deltaScale)

self.shape?.frame.size = newSize
self.shape?.center = self.originalCentre!

self.shape?.shapeSize = newSize
self.shape?.setNeedsDisplay()
```

As the pinch-zoom gesture completes, I calculate the factor:

```
let xScale = Double(newSize.width) / Double(currentSize.width)
let yScale = Double(newSize.height) / Double(currentSize.height)

self.points = self.points.map{(thisPoint) -> UIView in
       thisPoint.center = CGPoint(x: Double(thisPoint.center.x) * xScale, y: Double(thisPoint.center.y) * yScale)

       return thisPoint
}
```

(I was using CGFloats, but switched to Doubles in the hope that it would give me the precision I needed. Alas.)

Comment: I'm assuming your points are subviews of the circle?  If so, where is the bounds origin for the circle?  It would probably need to be in the middle of the circle for the code above to work right.  You might also want to consider storing the point location in degrees, and then just recalculate the point position using sin/cos during each resize.

Comment: I wanted to avoid being too circle-y about my calculations because a circle is one of many types of shape that I might need to place points on top of. It might be a square, or a jagged-looking line. If there were a way to calculate distance from the start of the line, I might do that (iOS doesn't seem to offer this). Yes, I am calculating based on the centre bounds. Does this help? :-)

Comment: Casting to Double isn't going to get you anything because you are starting with CGFloats to begin with (which is already a Double on 64 bit anyway).  Looking at it, deltaScale == xScale == yScale, right?  Might want to check to see if those values match to debug.

Comment: @mikepj Thanks for your help so far. I'm on board with the idea that I need to base this on the shape itself rather than points in a view. I've been working with different approaches, but I think the math on this is simply over my head! I have to do more research and come up with a different question before I can proceed. Sadly, this overall question may be DOA.

Answer (score 2):

You're accumulating roundoff errors. This is getting executed repeatedly:

```
       thisPoint.center = CGPoint(x: Double(thisPoint.center.x) * xScale, y: Double(thisPoint.center.y) * yScale)
```

Repeating any calculation of the form 'x=f(x)' with anything less than unlimited precision will result in drift.

Trick is to not have 'thisPoint.center' on both sides of the equal sign. Best way to do that is to have thisPoint.center be a pure function of some other state. Commenter suggested storing desired angle, that would work well. Then you could do:

thisPoint.center = f(thisPoint.someRadians), where 'f' converts from [polar to rectangular coordinates](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert%20polar%20to%20rectangular&oq=convert%20polar%20to%20rectangular&aqs=chrome..69i57.4303j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8), factoring in the scale of the circle.

Comment: Hi Loren, such an honour to have response from you! I think you've put your finger on what I suspected but mis-identified as a precision problem. My math is very weak, which is my biggest stumbling block, but I think I gather your intention here. Thanks for the link to info on polar coordinates; this may hold some answers for me.